# How to create a semi-transparent instruction page in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android and trying to work on this problem for last 2 days but could find a solution. Any help will be highly appreciated. How to create a semi-transparent page for instruction as used by an App Calorie Counter in Android Market?

[image: Instruction page in Android]

Comment: @PedroRainho Yes, I tried to do one of these in my App `Wordlist Builder`. Have a look at Google play? If it is useful, I can share code with you.

Comment: Hi can u please tell how did u do that?

Comment: can you touch on the layer behind the semi transparent layer ??

Comment: @user2078315 No, you have to dismiss the semi-transparent layer first.

Comment: there is any way to achieve what I wrote earlier ..

Comment: @user2078315 Ask another question, looks like you are looking for something different.

Comment: ok I'll do this ... thanks for giving your precious time here ...

Comment: hi @GauravAgarwal, did you manage to draw curvy arrow like the picture?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan You can see my implementation here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wissenways.wordlistbuilder&hl=en

Comment: @GauravAgarwal how you do that? with imageView or draw curvy line or ...? can you help me?

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan If you are not in hurry, give me few days I will upload the complete source code for the app on github.

Comment: @Shayanpourvatan Pushed source code for app [Wordlist Builder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wissenways.wordlistbuilder) to Github [here](https://github.com/agarwlGaurav/Wordlist-Builder). Leave comment on repo if you need my attention.

Answer (score 37):

Create a new activity and set the top-level view to have a translucent background:

```
android:background="#c0000000"
```

EDIT: You also need to declare the activity to have a transparent background. Setting this theme for the activity in the manifest will work:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
```

Comment: @GauravAgarwal Oops. I left out a step. I edited my answer to show what's needed.

Comment: Thanks it works now. How to draw arrows and point them at right coordinates in the paused activity?

Comment: @GauravAgarwal This is really a different question. I would suggest that before pausing the content activity, look up the screen coordinates of each area of interest (using `getLocationInWindow` for each view of interest) and pass those coordinates in the intent that starts the overlay activity. Your overlay activity will have to use a custom main view that can turn those coordinates into arrows.

Comment: I will try to do as you said. I think there should be some other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 12):

I just implemented Ted's answer in one of my projects. Great! Extremely easy to implement and great looking result. Many thanks for this Ted.

But as Stack Overflow is for taking and sharing I would like to share my implementation of a customized view that creates arrows in the form of a "needle" that I used with Ted's approach to make the original answer complete. Here is the code:

```
package com.yourpackage;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import de.nantoka.miep.R;

public class CoachmarkArrow extends View {

    private static final float CIRCLE_RADIUS = 1.5f;
    private static final int TOPLEFT = 0;
    private static final int TOPRIGHT = 1;
    private static final int BOTTOMLEFT = 2;
    private static final int BOTTOMRIGHT = 3;

    Paint paint;
    int from, to;

    PointF padding = new PointF();
    PointF fromPoint = new PointF();
    PointF toPoint = new PointF();

    public CoachmarkArrow (Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CoachmarkArrow, 0, 0);

        getPaint(a);
        getFromTo(a);

        a.recycle();
    }

    private void getFromTo(TypedArray a) {

        from = a.getInt(R.styleable.CoachmarkArrow_from, BOTTOMLEFT);
        to = a.getInt(R.styleable.CoachmarkArrow_to, TOPLEFT);
    }

    private void getPaint(TypedArray a) {
        paint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(a.getColor(R.styleable.CoachmarkArrow_color, Color.WHITE));
        paint.setStrokeWidth(a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CoachmarkArrow_size, 0));

        paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.BUTT);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw (Canvas canvas){
        calculatePadding(canvas);
        calculateLinePoints();

        drawLine(canvas, fromPoint, toPoint);
        drawCircle(canvas, fromPoint);
    }

    private void calculateLinePoints() {
        fromPoint = getPoint(from);
        toPoint = getPoint(to);
    }

    private void calculatePadding(Canvas canvas) {

        padding.x = CIRCLE_RADIUS * paint.getStrokeWidth() / canvas.getWidth();
        padding.y = CIRCLE_RADIUS * paint.getStrokeWidth() / canvas.getHeight();
    }

    private PointF getPoint(int position) {
        PointF point = new PointF();

        if (position == TOPRIGHT || position == BOTTOMRIGHT){
            point.x = 1.0f - padding.x;
        }
        else {
            point.x = padding.x;
        }

        if (position == BOTTOMLEFT || position == BOTTOMRIGHT){
            point.y = 1.0f - padding.y;
        }
        else {
            point.y = padding.y;
        }       

        return point;
    }

    private void drawCircle(Canvas canvas, PointF fromPoint) {

        canvas.drawCircle(
                canvas.getWidth() * fromPoint.x, 
                canvas.getHeight() * fromPoint.y, 
                CIRCLE_RADIUS * paint.getStrokeWidth(), 
                paint
                );
    }

    private void drawLine(Canvas canvas, PointF fromPoint, PointF toPoint) {
        canvas.drawLine(
                canvas.getWidth() * fromPoint.x, 
                canvas.getHeight() * fromPoint.y, 
                canvas.getWidth() * toPoint.x, 
                canvas.getHeight() * toPoint.y, 
                paint
                );
    }
}
```

Add this class to your project (any package name is fine) and create an attribute file under res/values for the XML parameters:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CoachmarkArrow">
        <attr name="size" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="color" format="color" />
        <attr name="from" format="enum">
            <enum name="topleft" value="0"/>
            <enum name="topright" value="1"/>
            <enum name="bottomleft" value="2"/>
            <enum name="bottomright" value="3"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="to" format="enum">
            <enum name="topleft" value="0"/>
            <enum name="topright" value="1"/>
            <enum name="bottomleft" value="2"/>
            <enum name="bottomright" value="3"/>
        </attr>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Now you can create the "needles" in the XML-Layout of your coachmarks activity like any other view, for example

```
<com.yourpackage.CoachmarkArrow
    xmlns:coachmark="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.yourproject"    
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    coachmark:size="3dip"
    coachmark:color="@android:color/white"
    coachmark:from="bottomright"
    coachmark:to="topleft"
/>
```

creates a "needle" that has the head at the bottom right and the tip at the top left corner of a rectangle that is 100 dp high and as wide as the containing parent ViewGroup.

That way you can create coachmarks that adapt automatically to the different screen sizes. For example, if you use a relative layout, create a dummy view for the UI element you want to describe in your coachmarks activity, and tell the relative layout to put the coach mark below the dummy view but above the explanation text box that you center in the middle of the window. That way the coachmark gets automatically the right size to point from the text box to the UI element.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Thank you for posting this, works well. The only trouble I had was with the attr name="color" in the styleable, now says it's already defined. Apparently something has changed in the Android dev tools. Just changed it to "kolor" and works fine.

Comment: @Nantoka - I am a newbie, i am not getting where to add this and how to get started. Can you help me out ?

Comment: @Bibhu - I can create a rough sketch of the steps but I am afraid you must try to roughly understand the details of this solution yourself. Here we go: 1) Create a new activity with a translucent background as described in the answer of Ted Hopp 2) Copy the source code of my CoachmarkArrow class into the src directory 3) Copy the XML parameters in a file under res/values 4) Design the UI layout or the activity with the translucent background using the CoarcharkArrow widgets as in the example 4) Start the activity with an intent so that it will cover the activity you made the coachmarks for

Comment: @Nantoka - Thanks, I did the same and it worked out. But one problem i am facing is finding out the position of the "button / control" to which i want to point. Can you suggest how to so ?

Comment: @Bibhu - I do this with "trial and error" as it would be quite complicated to write UI elements that replace the original UI elements with the coachmarks. And make sure you test your design on devices with different display sizes to make sure the arrows appear exactly where you want to have them.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried to do something similar. I have made message dialog with use of Activity. For this activity I wrote in Manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MessDial"
 android:label="@string/lblDialog"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent">
</activity>
```

In the body of this activity I don't have anything special fro transparency.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: How could you right messages with arrows pointing as shown in the figure of question?

Comment: I didn't understand your question now. I have seen it like a screen with some info and taping this screen it should close. Everything you put inside this screen is another question, not about transparency.

Comment: My question was also about the instruction page not just transparency.

Comment: The easiest one is to make one big image with all the information and transparent background. In this way you will probably need to make it for each type of screen, i.e. small, media, large. And then make listener for clicks on this image.

Comment: Please clarify what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this example for showing first time instruction screen without any other libraries
if you want to show instruction only at the first time, you can add some flags to Preference storage. An example can be found [here](http://d-codepages.com/index.php/android/coding-brginners/8-app-tutorial-screen-instruction-screen)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    SharedPreferences pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    boolean check = pref.getBoolean("firstime", true);
    if(check==true){
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Tutorial_screen.class);//starting activity for the Frist time
        startActivity(i);
    }
```